# Radio button is not holding value

Tags: html, django, radio-button

I am using a radio button it is working but while updating form that radio button is not holding values.
I am using it in Django template language. Here is my code:

```
<div class="span4" style="text-align:right"><label>Choice 1</label></div>
<div class="span1 controls">
   <input type="radio" name="cd_is_full_code" value="True" {% if cd_is_full_code == "True" %} checked {% endif %}>
</div>
<div class="span4" style="text-align:right"><label>Choice 2</label></div>
<div class="span1 controls">
   <input type="radio" name="cd_is_full_code" value="False" {% if cd_is_full_code == "False" %} checked {% endif %}>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text that you want to show should be within the `<input>` tag, as

```
<input type="radio" name="cd_is_full_code" value="True" {% if cd_is_full_code == "True" %} checked {% endif %}> 
     Text to show 
 </input>
```